# when should I converting back from transformation?

Tags: r, transform

I have response variable with right skewed distribution. so I did log transformation on response variable(nothing on predictor variables). Then, I ran OLS with log transformed response variable.

And I tried to predict the linear model to test set data.
The problem comes in here.
Briefly, I will show the code.

```
    rmse1<-sqrt(mean(sum((predicted_value - original_value)^2)))
    exp(rmse1)

    rmse2<-sqrt(mean(sum((exp(predicted_value) - exp(original_value))^2)))
```

I thought these should be same, but the results are different.
Which one is right one??

Comment: It depends whether you want the rmse of your original values or the transformed values.  Assuming the former, you probably need `sqrt(mean(sum((exp(predicted_value) - original_value)^2)))`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'd like to find rmse of original value.
So `sqrt(mean(sum((exp(predicted_value) - exp(original_value))^2)))` 
Is this right? because I also transformed response variable of test set.
This 'original value' means value of response variable from test set.

Comment: I don't think you need to `exp` the `original_value`, unless that is also log-transformed from the 'original' `original_value`.  So, if that is really `log_original_value`, then you are right!